# Single cascading drop down(alternative to what is used in ASP.net)

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseout

I have been working on a single cascading select drop down, which is an alternative to the standard cascading drop down used in ASP.net .
The thing is I have implemented half of it but not able to do with hover out events properly.

The only thing now I need is to hide secondary menu when mouse moves out of it.
I have used `("classname:hover").length` but this doesn't work all the time.

**Refer the image:**

[image]

Please find the plugin in the mentioned URL http://jsfiddle.net/nakul2111/deb0q5s8/

```
<div class='custom'></div>
<br><br>
<input type='text' >
<div class='drop'>

<ul class='ul-lev-1 ul'>
  <li class='li-lev-1' data-attr='oo1'>India<span class='arrow'>>></span></li>
<li class='li-lev-1'>Sri Lanka</li>
<li class='li-lev-1' data-attr='oo2'>USA<span class='arrow'>>></span></li>
<li class='li-lev-1'>Australia</li>
</ul>

<ul  data-attr='oo1' class='ul-lev-2 ul'>
<li class='li-lev-2'>Goa</li>
<li class='li-lev-2' data-attr='oo1-1'>Delhi<span class='arrow'>>></span></li>
<li class='li-lev-2'>J & K</li>
<li class='li-lev-2' data-attr='oo1-2'>UP<span class='arrow'>>></span></li>
</ul>

  <ul  data-attr='oo2' class='ul-lev-2 ul'>
<li class='li-lev-2' data-attr='oo2-1'>California<span class='arrow'>>></span></li>
<li class='li-lev-2'>Florida</li>
<li class='li-lev-2' data-attr='oo2-2'>Hawaii<span class='arrow'>>></span></li>
<li class='li-lev-2' data-attr='oo2-3'>Texas<span class='arrow'>>></span></li>
</ul>

<ul  data-attr='oo1-1' class='ul-lev-3 ul'>
<li class='li-lev-3'>VIvek VIhar</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>VAsant Kunj</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Dwarka</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Janakpuri</li>
</ul>

<ul  data-attr='oo1-2' class='ul-lev-3 ul'>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Ghaziabad</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Kausahambi</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Meerut</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Kanpur</li>
</ul>

<ul  data-attr='oo2-1' class='ul-lev-3 ul'>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Los Angeles</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>San Diego</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>San Jose</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Anaheim</li>
</ul>

<ul  data-attr='oo2-2' class='ul-lev-3 ul'>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Oahu</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Honolulu</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Hilo</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Maui</li>
</ul>

<ul  data-attr='oo2-3' class='ul-lev-3 ul'>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Houston</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Dallas</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>El Paso</li>
<li class='li-lev-3'>Waco</li>
</ul>
</div>

.custom{width:200px;
padding:5px;
height:20px;
border:1px solid #ccc;}
ul{list-style: none; padding:0; display:none;}
ul li{padding:5px;}
.ul-lev-1, .ul-lev-2, .ul-lev-3{position:absolute}
.ul {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:200px;
  background: #fff;
}
.ul li {
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
.ul li:hover{
  background:#ccc;
}
.ul li:last-child{border-bottom: none;}
.arrow {
     height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  margin-right:15px
}

$(".custom").click(function(){
  $('.ul-lev-1').show();
});
/*positioning the element start*/
 var offse = $('.custom').offset()
 $('.ul-lev-1').css({top:  offse.top+$('.custom').height(), left: offse.left}) 
/*positioning the element end*/
$('.ul li').hover(function(){
  if($(this).attr('data-attr')){    
    var dis = $(this);
    var disTop = dis.offset().top-15;
    var disLeft = dis.offset().left + dis.width()+10;

    var attr1 = $('.drop').find('.ul-lev-2');
    var attr2 = $('.drop').find('.ul-lev-3');

    if($(this).hasClass('li-lev-1')){
        attr1.each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("ul-lev-2") && dis.attr('data-attr') == $(this).attr('data-attr')){
         var offe2 = $(this).offset();
           $(this).show();
        $(this).css({
          top:disTop, 
          left:disLeft
        })     
      }
    })
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('li-lev-2')){
        attr2.each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("ul-lev-3") && dis.attr('data-attr') == $(this).attr('data-attr')){
         var offe3 = $(this).offset();
           $(this).show();
        $(this).css({
          top:disTop, 
          left:disLeft
        })     
      }
    })
    }  
  }
});

$('.ul li').mouseleave(function() { debugger;
        if($('body:hover').length){
  //  $('.ul-lev-3, .ul-lev-2').hide();
    }
    if ($(this).attr('data-attr')) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("li-lev-1")) {
            if (!$('.ul-lev-2:hover').length) {
                $('.ul-lev-2').hide();
            }
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass("li-lev-2")) {
            if (!$('.ul-lev-3:hover').length) {
                $('.ul-lev-3').hide();
            }             
        }         
    }
    else{
    if ($(this).hasClass("li-lev-3")) {debugger;
            if ($('.ul-lev-3:hover').length ) {
             //   $('.ul-lev-3').hide();
                console.log('hidden');
            }
            else
            if( $('body:hover').length){
             $('.ul-lev-3').hide();
             $('.ul-lev-2').hide();
            }
        }
         if ($(this).hasClass("li-lev-2")) {
            if (!$('.ul-lev-2:hover').length) {
                $('.ul-lev-2').hide();
              //  console.log('hidden');
            }             
        }}
})
```

Comment: Not clear what specific problem is. Explain behavior expected and how it differs from what current code does

Comment: i suggest you to try `if($(selection).is(':hover')){` syntax, but maybe you should have a look to the jQuery `hover` function, it could be a simpler way for you to handle your mouse events

Comment: @charlietfl : I have uploaded a pic, hope it clarifies . Please check it.

Comment: @Kaddath: if($(selection).is(':hover')){  , this was the first thing I tried. Doesn't work, it shows
 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover

Comment: sorry i misread the first part. you actually use `hover`, but with `mouseleave`, which is strange, `hover` takes 2 arguments, the function when it enters, the function when it leaves: `hover(handleIn, handleOut)`. You should also try to design your code so that elements handle themselves when mouse enters or leaves, not by trying to access directly to other ones states. If you still cant do it, i'll give a detailled answer

Comment: @Kaddath i understood your point, but my concern is something else. after hoverout I want to check if cursor is over any other menu. If yes then that menu shouldn't be hidden. that is why i mentioned **("classname:hover").length** is not working all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There would be different ways to answer directly to your question, but the problem actually lies elsewhere, so i will detail a little. Let's assume we want to reinvent the wheel as a test case. The code here is not the perfect solution to your question, because it can be improved (for some of the reasons below), but it illustrates what i want to tell.

- It is not because jQuery selectors are easy to use that they are the good way to dynamically get information about the DOM. If you use the same `id` selector twice in a function, the DOM will be parsed twice. The code must be thought as to access less as possible to elements directly from the selector, and rather store the result in a variable to re-use it.

=> For that point, the fiddle could be improved as a function that constructs from an array representing the menu, and stores the jQuery menu elements depending on their level, to be able to add and remove classes easily on them.

- there are at least two approaches when handling objects: there can be a general handler that controls everything, and handlers on the object themselves. I think that when one these system tries to do what the other should do, there is a design problem (in your code, you put a handler on each element, and each element tries to parse the whole menu to get their states, as if was a general handler). If you want to put the control at the level of the element, the element should only care about what is accessible to him, or eventually trigger element controls to his parent or children.

=> For that point, the code could be improved by nesting the lists in the html code for exemple, as to match the hierarchy of the sub-menus. The html elements would be containing themselves and could be found by hierarchy. There would be no need to store an id or class to find the sub-menu to show it, and rather look the children list. So elements that have handlers on them could directly act on accessible objects rather than having to parse the DOM to find them.

**code exemple:** like i said this is not a perfect answer, it just shows that what you want to achieve can be re-thought into another simpler question: for example if one list element hides all sub-elements of a deeper level before showing the sub-menu, there is no need to check all the hover states of the menus actually, just to identify what menus to hide.

I simplified with just a part of the menu, and no CSS

https://jsfiddle.net/2a2142s6/3/